# Microsoft Dynamics API - Getting Fields from Entity with Navigation

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dataverse

I am trying to get the field list from an entity,  in example contact, I have successfully done it doing a Request to:

```
EntityDefinitions(LogicalName='contact')/Attributes/Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.AttributeMetadata
```

But now I need to get the Navigation Properties defined on this entity, I have found information on how to get Navigation Properties when querying a specific record by id,  but in this case I need it when getting the field list.

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 2):

Referring the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/data-platform/webapi/query-metadata-web-api

You already have the Lookup attributes, `AttributeMetadata` has *everything*.
If you want to only read the metadata of lookups, change the type to `LookupAttributeMetadata`.

```
EntityDefinitions(LogicalName='contact')/Attributes/Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.LookupAttributeMetadata
```

To obtain relationships info alongside the columns list then an additional query is required, `RelationshipDefinitions`:

```
/RelationshipDefinitions/Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.OneToManyRelationshipMetadata
/RelationshipDefinitions/Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.ManyToManyRelationshipMetadata

filter on ReferencedEntity / ReferencingEntity to limit the results
```

```
/RelationshipDefinitions/Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.ManyToManyRelationshipMetadata 

filter on Entity1LogicalName / Entity2LogicalName / IntersectEntityName
```

Comment: thanks for the information. I have 2 questions: a) by using AttributeMetadata I do not see Navigation Options or Relationships,is. it possible. to get it in one query? b) using LookupAttributeMetadata looks interesting, how can I get the Attributes without the lookup ones already got with this query?

Comment: both) Not possible, as far as I know

Comment: On the second one I guess I can do: EntityDefinitions(LogicalName='contact')/Attributes/Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.AttributeMetadata?$filter=AttributeType ne 'Lookup', in that way I can get the LookUp attributes in a separate call.